# Add ciphers support?

Tags: ssh

EditPlus can connect to SFTP only with `3DES` or `AES128-CBC` encryption. But Jessie doesn't seem to support it! I'm getting error that Could not agree encryption algorithm and few algorithms comma separated...

So i tried to add support by editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`...

Uncommented line:

```
Ciphers 3des,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

As you can see `aes128-cbc` is there.... but after `sudo service sshd restart` still the same... can't connect from EditPlus, and same list of supported ciphers... What's wrong? How do I enable it?

Comment: Try setting PasswordAuthentication yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (not ssh_config).

Comment: Please don't do that. Update your EditPlus software to something up-to date, rather then downgrading ciphers supported by the server. These two are already partially broken.

Comment: @Jakuje can't... no new version, and I got used to EditPlus for years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So i tried to add support by editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

As per [joan's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan), there is a difference between `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`:

- `ssh_config` provides a default configuration for SSH *clients* connecting *from* this machine to another machine's ssh server, aka. `sshd`; here `d` is for [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).  Servers of all kinds usually but not necessarily operate in this mode.
- `sshd_config` provides configuration for this machine's ssh *server*, `sshd`.

This can get a bit confusing because sometimes (I think this is the case on Raspbian), the init service which starts the ssh daemon (`sshd`) is just called `ssh`, which is also the name of the ssh *client*.

So, if you are trying to ssh into the pi, you are trying to connect to an `sshd` running there (technically there can be more than one, but this would be unusual).  This includes making sftp connections. **The default configuration for this server is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.**

There are separate man pages, see `man sshd_config` and `man ssh_config`.  These go into more detail with regard to the possible options in each file.

---

There's also a likely problem with your list of ciphers; if you look in `man sshd_config` under **Ciphers** you'll see a list, but since this is a hardcoded, stock manual page, it's also worth noting that you get an actual list of what's really available on the machine with `ssh -Q cipher`.  E.g., I notice on a recent Raspbian Jessie that list has one additional entry for rijndael-cbc (which I think is probably an alternate implementation of one of the aes-cbc cipher).  Anyway...

```
Ciphers 3des,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
        ^^^^
```

I think one of these is not available.  You might get more information about the error by running `sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog` after trying to restart the server.

Comment: but when i copy that line with Ciphers from ssh_config to sshd_config, I am getting sshd error when restarting and until commenting it, the server won't run again, won't accept new connection (good that it keeps the old one alive).

Comment: I've added a speculation about this.

Comment: It actually worked :) Just used ciphers aes128-cbc and it works fine :) now it supports only one but putty works and editplus too, so its great :) thanx.